# Do the floor and ceiling functions count as closed-form expressions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, definition, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression):

> a closed-form expression is a mathematical expression expressed using a finite number of standard operations

I'm not sure if  the floor and ceiling functions are considered standard in many scenarios. Regardless, suppose I have an expression that uses a finite amount of standard operations and floor or ceiling functions, is that expression closed form?

As a computation, the floor and ceiling functions are definitely computable with an algorithm of finite steps.

For example, one could define the floor function as: $\lfloor x\rfloor=x-(x$ mod $1)$

Would that definition qualify as closed?

Comment: Whoever uses the expression closed form or standard should say what counts.  There is no official list.  I would count floors and ceilings, but others would not.  How about Bessel functions, Hermite functions, Lambert W, Jacobi functions, etc.?

Comment: If you define the floor function as $\lfloor x\rfloor=x-(x\bmod1)$, then you still have to define $x\bmod1$.

Comment: What is and is not a closed form is dependent entirely on what you consider to be a standard function. I think the question of what is and is not standard is not a mathematical one, but one of convention. In your example, I doubt anyone would object to the floor function being "standard", but again, that is up to the individual.

Comment: They are elementary functions since they are expressible in terms of $\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))$, except at discontinuities.